# Angular ERROR TypeError: "[element] is undefined"

Tags: angular

I've create methods to manipulate some data, the code compiles and when i goes to the browser, it says what are on the title. Some of the codes

```
copyList(listSrc: any[], listDest: any[]){
    listSrc.forEach(elem => {
      listDest.push(elem);
    })
}
```

so then

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.copyList(this.exampleList, this.exampleListAux);
  }
```

other codes like this one i have the same error

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var date: Date;
    date.setMinutes(50);
    console.log(date.getTime());
}
```

on what i call [element] in title, is 'listDest' on the first case, and 'date' on the second

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? you do not need to loop through for copying list. `listDest = Array.from(listSrc)`

Comment: works for the first case, not for the second

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code in ngOnInit like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMinutes(50);
  console.log(date.getTime());
}
```

And you will see result in the console.

Comment: What's the difference between your code and the question?

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi

In author code: var date: Date;
In my code: var date = new Date();

In the author case **date** is **undefined**, and in my case **date** is a **Date object**. Do you feel the difference?